# How to rectify error WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, virtualenv

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Whenever I use pip3 for eg I did `pip3 install virtualenvwrapper-win`

I get `WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`

Also for this specific module virtualenvwrapper I am getting

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenvwrapper-win (from 
versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Installing anything with pip works fine but pip here is associated with python2.7, it's just pip3 that's not working.

I searched stackoverflow and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164352/cannot-use-pip-ubuntu-pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl) but the accepted answer provided is not working for me. More specifically if I do `sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev`

I get `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Please help me to fix pip3.

Answer (score 0):

In windows this error / warning is because of below three paths not added in Windows environment variable :

1. ....\Anaconda\Library\bin
2. ....\Anaconda\Scripts
3. ....\Anaconda

If not using Anaconda then in place of Anaconda the path where python (Python Executables) is installed.